# android create google plus like profile image

Tags: android, bitmap, google-plus

Hello I would like to create a circular image witch has a small border and inside loads the users profile picture, just like google plus android application does.
The problem is that I need to set that image in as a drawable top of a Button, so I have found this code:

```
public BitmapDrawable putOverlay(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap overlay) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, paint);
    return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}
```

witch is supposed to overlay one bitmap (users pic) over another bitmap (oval shaped) but the think is that a) the circular bitmap is over the user's profile pic, and b) the user's profile pic is too large.
Any suggestions on how to do this or if I am at least on the right way is much appreciated.

UPDATE

I have managed to show the two images using this code:

```
public BitmapDrawable putOverlay(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap overlay) {
    int width = overlay.getWidth()-50;
    int height = overlay.getHeight()-50;

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height,true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(width,height);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, matrix, null); 
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.drawBitmap(b,matrix, null);
    BitmapDrawable completeImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),overlay);
    return completeImage;
}
```

the problem is that the profile picture is not aligned into the circulare image.Its like the profile picture is drawn from the same x,y position the circulare image is drawn.
Also please note that the profile picture is loaded using :

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(imagepath).getContent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code (first scales the profile pic then applies the overlay)

```
public BitmapDrawable putOverlay(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap overlay) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, overlay.getWidth(), overlay.getHeight(),true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, paint);
    return new BitmapDrawable(b);
}
```

I didn't quite get what you meant in problem a that the overlay is on top of the profile pic

Comment: no this didn't do the trick, what I mean is that I would like to create an image like google plus android application has to show the users profile in the main dashboard. To do this I read an image that is just a plain white circle and then try to overlay the actual image from the users profile. Instaed of showing the profile image in from of the white circle the opposite is occuring.

Comment: you could just pass an overlay image that is a white square, with a circle cut out of it in the center, this way the above code will produce the wanted effect.